# Laravel Collection filter into Parent Data

Tags: laravel

I have created map table for relation between Products & Product Categories. I want to get Product object from collection using below code.

```
return  $collection->products->product_categories()->get()->filter(function($item) use ($itemIds)
                {
                    if(isset($item->pivot->parent->id))
                    {   
                        return $item->pivot->parent;    
                    }

                });
```

If I dump and die parent then I can see Product object but when I try to return Product it shows Category data.

Comment: how did you map the relations in the model? So you basically want to get the products in certain categories, right?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You just need to return the product data from the categories. Assuming your code works, you just have to map the collection to return the parent from the pivot.

```
    return  $collection->products->product_categories()->get()->filter(function($item) use ($itemIds)
                        {
                            if(isset($item->pivot->parent->id))
                            {   
                                return $item->pivot->parent;    
                            }

                        })->map(function($item){ 
                            return $item->pivot->parent; 
                        });
```